# При добавлении UIImageView на UIScrollView не происходит корректного скрола для Ipad сториборда

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, autolayout, uiscrollview

Есть два сториборда, под айфон и айпад. Под айфон в сториборде к UIScrollView уже подключен UIImageView корректно, при запуске на симуляторе все работает правильно и xcode никаких предуприждений не выдает. А в сториборде для айпад пытался аналогично подключить к UIScrollView тот же UIIMageView, но не получается, чтобы работало корректно и без предуприждений.

Под разные девайсы имеются два разных изображения по размеру, для айфона картинка с размером под 7+, а для айпада размер картинки для 12.9. При запуске симулятора 7+ картинка по высоте отображается полностью на всю высоту 7+, а по ширине скролится вправо, тк ширина картинки большая. Соответсвенно на меньших девайсах айфона, при отображении картинки, по высоте она будет занимать больше места, чем высота экрана телефона и скролится еще и вверх/вниз+вправо. Того же эфекта пытаюсь добится и для айпад. 
Пытался все привязать через reset to suggested, а так же просто добавить констренты для UIImageView относительно UIScrollView, но все равно не получается. Хотя делаю все так же, как делал для айфон.
https://yadi.sk/d/YPJKb90V3NCMjh